# Views exposed filter are cached

Tags: views

after performing a search using Views exposed filter,the filter is cached and even I change that I get the same as previously results.How can I solve that?
thanks

Comment: In your filter configuration did you select _Remember the last selection_? You can also set the caching for the view to _None_ under the Advanced settings.

Comment: I Am experience this same issue, even with the remember setting enabled and cache set to none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure these settings are set:

remember last selection & caching

[image]

[image]