# Relative date filter views block is cached for anonymous users

Tags: 7, views, blocks, caching, datetime

Drupal 7.74, views 3.24 (latest)

I have a view which uses a date field to filter and shows on: less than or equal to "now"

I display the view in a block.

With caching for anonymous enabled, (caching blocks disabled),  the view block is not shown when the date has passed (works for authenticated users)

Is this normal behaviour, am I missing something, or do I need to disable caching for the pages this block will appear on?

Thanks!

Edit: If I save the node in question, or run cron, the views block displays for anonymous users. Am I going to have to trigger something like that with Rules?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Views exposed filter are cached](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75554/views-exposed-filter-are-cached)

Comment: No, it's not an exposed filter and block caching in the view is set to the default 'none'